# Like with right value with wildcard percent

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I need to search for countries ids and I ran into a problem, for example, let's take the country "Bolivia".

The Country table has a "CountryName" and "Alternative Names"

For the example of "Bolivia".

```
IdCountry  Name                             Code  AlternateNames
---------- -------------------------------- ----- ---------------------------
29         Bolivia, Plurinational State Of  BO    Bolivia, Bolivien, Bolivie
```

This is the query I've created:

```
SELECT cou.CountryID 
FROM Doppler2011.dbo.Country cou 
WHERE (cou.AlternateNames IS NOT NULL AND 'Bolivia' like '%'+cou.AlternateNames+'%') 
        OR 'Bolivia' like cou.Name
```

As you see, I need the `cou.AlternateNames` in the Right side of the like to match the name of the country with some of the alternatives names, for the countries which the name is the same as the `cou.Name`, the query works, but the problem is with those that have to match with AlternateNames

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the `AlternateNames` stored together as a column value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have the wilcards on the other term like this

```
SELECT cou.CountryID 
        FROM Doppler2011.dbo.Country cou 
        WHERE cou.AlternateName like '%Bolivia%' OR cou.Name like 'Bolivia'
```

Comment: You're right, I dont know why this query confuse me so much... thanks!

Comment: Aaron Bertrand you are right, i'll edit. Mariano you are welcome.

Comment: I don't see how this would work. In the example the AlternateName is one of (Bolivia, Bolivien, Bolivie). `like '%Bolivia%'` will only ever match the first member of the set. It's very likely, though, that I'm misreading the question.

Comment: ... that is unless it's a comma-separated list stored in one column.

Comment: I think is a coma separated string stored in the AlternateName column

Comment: If it is a comma-separated list then it should be `',' + cou.AlternateName + ',' LIKE '%,Bolivia,%'` - this way you only match the full word.

Comment: @Swasheck I assumed they meant `LIKE '%Bolivi%'`

Comment: Thanks all, I found the problem, the value "Bolivia" is from other table, and in the other table is set as char(30), so it was 
"Bolivia_____"(with 30 chars) so the comparation always return false. but thanks to Ateszki and a lot of test, I could fix the query

Answer (score 1):

your where clause is basically backwards.
you normally say:

```
COLUMN_NAME like '%string_to_match%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your actual structure here are some thoughts.

If `AlternateName` is stored as a comma-separated list on one column value, and `Name` is always the first value of the list in `AlternateName` then you can use [Ateski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15300037/251174)

If it's not the first item in the list, then you'd need to follow @AaronBertrand's advice in his comment:

```
SELECT cou.CountryID 
    FROM Doppler2011.dbo.Country cou 
    WHERE ',' + cou.AlternateName + ',' LIKE '%,Bolivia,%' 
      OR cou.Name ='Bolivia';
```

Finally, if you could re-work your structure a bit so that you have a list of possible country names, you could come up with something like this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d3c8/1

Just an alternate perspective. Ateski's solution is perfectly valid and good.